# file upload with cypress is not working for PDF

Tags: cypress, cypress-file-upload

even if it looks file uploaded but it didn`t , can someone tell me how can i upload pdf file with cypress

cy.get("div.button").attachFile({
filePath:'form.pdf',
mimeType:'application/pdf',
encoding:"base64"
},
{force:true,
uploadType:"input"}
)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM1zp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cy.get(div.button)` seems like you are targetting the wrong element. The correct element must be of type `input` not type `div`

Take a close look at the HTML to find the correct selector

Comment: <div ng-if="form.display === 'pdf' &amp;&amp; !form.settings.pdf" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngInclude: --><input type="hidden" ng-model="form.type" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty"><ng-include src="'views/form/upload.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">Upload a PDF</h3>
<div class="ng-scope">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block">
    <div class="button" ngf-select="upload($file)" ngf-pattern="'application/pdf'" accept="application/pdf" ngf-max-size="20MB"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload PDF</div>
  </label>

Comment: this is the code until button, i cannot locate with input, sorry for sharing like this , domehow i could not include img

Comment: It's in the 2nd line of what you posted. Could you try ```cy.get('input.ng-pristine')``` for example?

Comment: I could handle one part of the pdf with your answer but not this one, I can locate it with cy.get('input.ng-pristine') but still the same thing, it shows uploaded  but it didn't